# Apache serving files that should not be served

Tags: apache, webserver, hosting, web-hosting, self-hosting

Today I discovered that my fresh installation of **Apache** HTTP Server is able to serve files from my `C:\uploads\` **directory**.

I have two folders in `C:\uploads`:

- C:\uploads\templates
- C:\uploads\sites

Both folders contain `testimage.jpg`.

I found that Apache will serve the files from the templates folder if I request:

http://localhost/templates/testimage.jpg

However, http://localhost/sites/testimage.jpg **404**'s!

OMG - firstly, why does Apache serve the *templates* folder in the first place? Is it special?

Secondly, by what arbitrary set of rules does apache disallow access to other folders such the sites?

I'm so confused.  Perhaps I've taken a wrong turn somewhere during the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look through your httpd.conf file to see what rules are in place for what is being served?  Alternatively, are there .htaccess files that may be changing what is being served?  You might have templates exposed in one or the other, but not sites... that's the first thing that comes to mind.

I would suggest going through these configuration files with a fine toothed comb to see what may cause the behavior you see.